# What do I enter as the server and delegate URLs for using delegation with my Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: support, openid

I've been using OpenID [delegation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/) with MyOpenID.  I want to do the same with a Stack Exchange OpenID, but I'm not sure what to enter as the server and delegate URLs.  Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've added an easier way to get at the data needed for OpenID delegation.

First, go to the Open ID site for Stack Exchange:

https://openid.stackexchange.com/

And login.  From there, you'll be taken to your [profile page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user).  It's also available via the "Profile" button at the top:

[image: Stack Exchange Open ID Profile button]

The "Use your own URL to log in" link is present below profile information.  Click it and you'll be presented with the markup to place in the `<head>` section of the HTML page served up by your URL:

[image: Stack Exchange Open ID "Use your own URL to log in" link]

Comment: Is there a way to use delegation via a DNS entry rather than the HTML method? I don't have hosting for the domain I want to use..

Comment: Apparently, this account is independent from regular profiles you may have at sites from the network such as Stack Overflow. You can just click on "Register" and create a new account. You'll still be able to use your delegated URL to log into your existing Stack Overflow account.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, delegation is a way to let your SE id be used in place for other openId. You have some délégation example on sourceforge.net to be able to use sf.net as openid for your Google openid or other.

At the moment I did not see anywhere in the SE openid interface any implementation of delegation. But maybe I'm wrong. By the way the service was beta some days ago, so it must satisfy only few functionalities.

Comment: [Well, actually,](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-17.html) delegation is a way to let you use a custom URL in place of the OpenID provider's URL.  You can then enter that custom URL wherever an OpenID is required.  Should you later wish to change OpenID providers, you only have to edit your delegate rather than having to enter the new provider's URL into all of those sites.

Comment: No the fact is you can't use a custom URL. You can use a provider's URL to mask other providers URL. This is understandable since a site should be able to request someone with the URL. Then you can allow this someone to act as another openid you have. But indeed the function has to be implemented. And I think it's not.

Comment: See [Using Your Own URL as Your OpenID](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/).