# How to delegate to SE's OpenID?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I enter as the server and delegate URLs for using delegation with my Stack Exchange OpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92965/what-do-i-enter-as-the-server-and-delegate-urls-for-using-delegation-with-my-stac)

My domain delegates OpenID authentication, so it has [tags like these](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#delegating_authentication) on the homepage:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="foo" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="bar" />
```

I'm a bit annoyed with my current OpenID provider, so I figured I'd switch to using the StackExchange one since I already have it registered. What do I put in the `link` tags to delegate to SE's OpenID? I figured `openid.server` should be `https://openid.stackexchange.com` and `openid.delegate` my profile URL, but I just end up on my profile (if logged in) or the generic "This is an OpenID identity provider for the Stack Exchange network." (if logged out)